# Entity Framework, Composite Key doesn't get created

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following classes:

```
public class GoodsIssueProcess
{

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), MaxLength(128)]
    public string DeliveryNote { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    // the unique ID of the product
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(36)]
    [Index("IX_ArticleNumber", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
}
```

(abbreviated for readability)

As you can see, the GoodsIssueProcess consists of a Product and a delivery note code (basically just a number). According to the specification of the "Key" keyword I would expect to get a composite primary key for ProductId and DeliveryNote. Yet, what I get is a normal Primary Key for DeliveryNote. The Product column even gets the Nullable attribute and a foreign key relationship to the Product table (which is fine).

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong? I have also tried assigning the following:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Product")]
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

The result was the same database layout (only a single primary key, no composite key). I'm working on EF 6.0 and MSSQL Server 2012.

EDIT:
Stop! - Apparently version #2 works (the one with public int ProductId). Yet, shouldn't the first version work as well?

Comment: The first version does not work. If you don't like to see ProductId property you can use a private backing field and fluent interface to map it and to set the key (the class containing the fluent interface map has to be an inner class of GoodsIssueProcess)

Comment: I don't really care if I see the ProductId but I would like to understand why the first version doesn't work. Is it because Product is no int/string which can be used for a primary key?

Comment: I don't know if EF likes to see navigation properties declared as key. I'm not too experienced with data annotations, but I think it might just ignore those key requirements on navigation properties.

Comment: A Key should be a column in database. Navigation Properties are not a column in database. I believe that's why it doesn't work

Comment: Actually indexes and primary keys can be only on primitive types. There's not really a logical reason, the attributes are just ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key parts of composite keys should be of types that can translate to primitive types in SQL, the type `Product` cannot be translated to primitive type but `ProductId` can be translated to `int` in SQL.
The composite key must be:

```
public class GoodsIssueProcess
{

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), MaxLength(128)]
    public string DeliveryNote { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```